# Heroku and Route 53 Cannot validate/verify domain / Domain incorrect settings (with ANSWER)

Tags: heroku, dns, amazon-route53

I have bought domain name on Amazon Route53, and I was trying to setup Heroku App with Amazone Route 53. To make this possible I was following this offical [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53), but it didin't work and I've got message that Heroku could not validate my domain (you can see on screenshot below):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is your case, but you should check this. Go to Amazone Route 53 Dashboard, and click on the Domain link:

[image]

Click on your domain and you will be redirected to the page with the domain details, and just pay attention to **Name servers** item in **Details** section:

[image]

Then open another tab, go to your **Hosted zones** page, open hosted zone within your domain, and click on the `NS` record.

[image]

Now you show to compare the `NS` record from the hosted zone and `Name servers`, you saw on the Domain details page (2 step).

If they are different, you have to click on `Actions` button on the Domain details page -> Edit name servers and replace them on one from `NS` record from Hosted zone page (step 3.2).

You have to wait some time for this change to be applied, for me it took a few hours.